# Implementing application level locking

Tags: locking

We have a requirement in our application where resources need to be locked before being accessed/modified to avoid concurrent operations and maintain integrity. Since there are a series of operations performed on the resource we decided to implement an application level locking concept which all the components accessing the resource will have to respect.

Note that the resource would be accessed/modified by multiple processes hence synchronization becomes an overhead. This was also one of the reasons to choose application level locking.

One of the approaches we have in mind for implementing application level locking is to insert and update entries in a database table which would have columns like resource name, lock type (would be read lock, write lock or full exclusive lock) and the information about the process which acquired the lock. We chose database table as an option since its the only component centralized to all the processes accessing the resource, but if someone could explore out other possibilities it would be helpful.

The other problem with the database approach is that the implementation has to use pessimistic locking. (Our application uses Oracle as our db server).

The intent of this question is to explore out various approaches of implementing application level locking.

**Edit 1**

The reason I mention that the database approach has to implement pessimistic locking is because

1. The resources which are accessed/modified by various application components are added dynamically by users in the software. Hence it would ugly to insert their entries always in this database table also.
2. Even if resource entries are made in this table the problem arises on when do we delete these entries?

A optimistic locking approach would have been good but I could not think about how do we implement it.

**Edit 2**
Adding details on the lock type
I have updated the above problem statement to specify that there are 3 lock types

1. Read Lock - Can be acquired if all the other locks are either read or write
2. Write Exclusive Lock - Can be acquired if all the other locks are read
3. Full Exclusive Lock - Can be acquired if there are no locks on this resource

Comment: What kind of application (web/GUI/CLI/etc.?) are you developing and in which programming language?

Comment: Its a web application which is deployed on glassfish clusters. The application is being developed in Java Programming language

Answer (score 3):

An additional field you might consider for your database style lock is a current time.  You may also consider agreeing that any operation from an application cannot take more than X amount of time.

The reasoning behind the suggestion is to prevent scenarios where a possible application crashes, loses connectivity to the database, etc and is unable to "undo" the lock.  Other applications would include functionality to remove the stale lock and create a new one.

You may also want the applications to insert the column, then wait a random amount of time and then attempt to check it again.  This could help reduce the possibility of applications colliding on a resource while they were waiting for the database to complete it's operations.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. The reason you mention adding a timestamp column is I assume having optimistic locking. Please have a look at my above edit for reasons I think optimistic locking cannot be implemented. The second point about recovery is also very much needed but I think that can be done with the information about the process which acquired the lock on a resource.  I didn't understand your third point about inserting a new column.

Comment: You mentioned "when do we delete these rows?" in the edit.  That is also to the second paragraph's point above - have the applications remove stale locks when they issue a lock.  The third paragraph was to stop a possible race condition when two applications attempt to lock the same resource at the EXACT same time.  The randomized time along with a second check for locks could prevent simultaneous access.

Comment: I have updated the problem description to specify details on lock types. Sorry for adding this info later. Can you explain me 1. When does the application update the timestamp column? 2. Won't there be a race condition when a different application removes a stale lock and create a new one and at the same time there is a request for a lock on that resource.  3. In your third paragraph, you mention that the application inserts a column. What is this new column for?.

Comment: Also since multiple locks can be acquired on the same resource there would have to be multiple rows for the same resource since maintain the process information becomes difficult if there is only one entry for each resource. This raises another problem of making the database operations on the resource atomic. To achieve atomicity, the only solution I could think of is to lock the table before hand which reduces concurrency and increasing the waiting time. Do you think there could be any better approach to this? Again thanks for your comments.

Comment: At a very basic level, what I had envisioned was something like this:  Application starts, inserts a row into the database with information like PID of the app, Name of the App (human readable), timestamp of lock.  It then waits a random amount of time between 1 and 5 seconds.  At that time, it checks to see if another program has a lock earlier than the one inserted.  If so, it removes the lock request and goes to sleep to retry later.  Otherwise, it considers itself the sole locking application and does it's work.  This should help reduce race conditions because of latency to the DB, etc.

Comment: There is a lot of room for improvement on the approach above.  I have used it on some basic things like updating files in a shared environment without a CMS and editing records from a web page.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. I have a few follow up questions (I will add them in batches of comments)
1. Since the resources are dynamically added in the software, the application will have to insert a row in this lock_resource table when the resource is added. If its not inserted at this moment in time, problem comes during runtime to determine if a row needs to be inserted/updated. In my mind the lock_resource table contains following columns - resource id, process_info, no_of_read_locks, no_of_write_locks, no_of_fullex_locks and timestamp.   ....continued.

Comment: Since the number of read locks, write locks and fullex locks are limited on a resource, I am thinking that the table will have those number of proces_info_columns. I am trying to fit all the information for a resource in one row so as to have optimistic locking approach instead of pessimistic. Taking all this into consideration I assume you meant that the timestamp column will have the current timestamp whenever a row is inserted and updated, right?

Comment: 2. First of all there are various issues with the above consideration like - Inserting a row into the lock_resource table when a resource is added needs to be synchronized. i.e. any failure in adding a resource needs to roll back the insertion of a row in the lock table. Deletion of resource from the software needs to delete the corresponding row from the lock_resource table. I am not sure if Oracle locking framework would lock the lock_resource table during this insertion and deletion since it would defeat our purpose to have optimistic locking.

Comment: 3. Now when an application requires a lock on a resource, it loads the current information for that resource, validates if lock can be acquired (based on the rules I specified in problem description) and then tries to update that row if everything is fine. If the update succeeds it means that lock is acquired else it means that other process has acquired the lock. I didn't understand the need for random wait time here. Can you please explain.

Comment: The main problem I see with the approach mentioned in my above comments is synchronizing the addition and deletion of the resources with the corresponding inserts and deletes in the lock_resource table. Also the lock_resource table will have those many entries in the database as the number of resources in the software which could be huge and does not seem appropriate. The lock_resource table will have entries for resources even if they do not need to be locked at that moment in time.